# How to represent an invalid edge in a graph in the code?

Tags: c++, c++11, graph

I'm implementing a graph structure and I have an `Edge` class with a `to` and a `from` member. I want to support connections to invalid nodes, for example if a user temporarily deletes a node, the edges to it shouldn't be removed - they should just set their `to` member to some invalid state.

In the book I'm reading, `to` and `from` are integers, and a value of `-1` represents an invalid node. Now I don't really like this, I don't think it is good style as it has no semantics at all associated with it.

I've been trying out different solutions but I'm a bit at a loss of what would work well. I was thinking about:

- an `enum class`, I don't think it would work
- a `union`, haven't worked with it yet but I also think it's not good for this use case
- a custom `Index` class with an integer member and a `bool isValid`, but this has problems as well, for example if `isValid` is `false`, what should `Index::getIndex()` return.
- my most recent idea: `boost::optional`? But I don't really want to encode an *optional* value, I want to express the fact that an index can be either an integer value or have an `Invalid` state.

How can I express what I want with good code?

Comment: The value `-1` is quite usual for something like this. Else, I would make a flag like in your third point, and what `getIndex` will return doesn´t matter because you should have a `isValid` too.

Comment: @deviantfan: But it would mean that at each call site of `getIndex()` the user has to make sure to check for `isValid()` first. `getIndex()` would return an undefined value in that case (the default integer value or whatever). I don't know, it seems to me like there must be a better way of doing that in modern C++ that correctly expresses the semantic meaning of the situation at hand (to make the code nice, robust and hard to misuse).

Comment: `But it would mean that at each call site of getIndex() the user has to make sure to check for isValid() first.` Yes, but else, you need `-1` again. `getIndex() would return an undefined value in that case` And that´s `-1`. ... Either you have something completely separate of the integer, or you´ll need a special integer value to express "invalid". There is no other way..

Comment: I've been making a road network graph and faced with this problem too, to be honest, there are two ways of solving this problem: 1 - store successors of each node and remove id's of `to` sucessors you don't need at the moment, so after that you take your Node and can easily find all 'existing" edges by iterating through successors array(list). 2 - use "-1" flag to skip edges.